# CSS3 Text Gradient on Android not working

Tags: android, css, webkit, gradient

I'm trying to use a text gradient, and it works on Chrome & Safari but on Android it applies the gradient to the content rather than the text (so instead of seeing text with a gradient, you see a box with a gradient — not ideal, especially since the text is important).

Here's my SASS mixin:

```
@mixin text-gradient($from : #2bd2f2, $to : #218bb2) {
    text-shadow: none;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from($from), to($to));
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    color: transparent;
}
```

Any idea as to why this doesn't work?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you have to use vendor prefixes for gradient.. like how you used for -webkit- for chrome browser like you have to mention for all browser vendor prefixes like -moz-, -o-

Comment: isn't android webkit, though?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. Implement this in your script and change out all the variables that you have if you like. If all else fails, you can use it as it is outside mixin.

This script is tested on Android Chrome and works.

```
h1 {
        text-shadow: none;
        background: #2bd2f2;  /* Failsafe color */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #2bd2f2), color-stop(99%, #218bb2));
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2bd2f2 0%, #218bb2 99%);
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2bd2f2 0%, #218bb2 99%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

As you might have figured out this method isn't very compatable with alot of browsers. Thats why i might recommend the canvas option in html5 to draw the text with the gradient.
These links could help you along the way.

https://www.inkling.com/read/html5-canvas-fulton-fulton-1st/chapter-3/text-and-the-canvas-context

https://www.inkling.com/read/html5-canvas-fulton-fulton-1st/chapter-3/text-with-gradients-and-patterns